# Brace matching highlight as outline for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

ReSharper has a feature which can highlight a code block between brackets. It's under `Highlight matching delimiters [...] > Hightlight with: outline`.

[image: Screenshot]

ReSharper is really expensive and I want only this specific feature so I don't want to buy it.

So maybe someone knows an extention which does this as well? It doens't have to be free, but it should at least be *much* cheaper then ReSharper.

Comment: For Visual Studio Code (not Visual Studio) there exists a free extension that does this: [Bracket Pair Colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer)